# Assign Width of First Letter of Word

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to set up a plugin and it works pretty good, but I noticed that the first character (F in First) wasn't being assigned the correct width on page load.  The plugin allows you to mouseover and it changes to Second word and then on mouseout, changes back to First word & then the first character's width is correct. So I tried this to fix it when it first shows:

```
var firstltrwdraw = $('span.char1').width(); // this width is actually 39px but it keeps pulling 27
 console.log('1st Width Raw: ' + firstltrwdraw);
var firstltrwd = parseFloat(firstltrwdraw);
  console.log('1st Width: ' + firstltrwd);
  console.log('1st Type: ' + typeof firstltrwd);
$('span.char1').parent().css({'width': firstltrwd + 'px'});
```

Here's some typ. html:

```
<div class="lslide_wrap">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" ...>
    <span class="sl-wrapper" ...>
      <span class="char1 sl-w2" ...>S</span> // first letter of Second
      <span class="char1 sl-w1" ...>F</span> // first letter of First
    </span>
    <span class="sl-wrapper" ...>
     ... // second letter of each word, etc
     ...
    <span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here's a demo page:  http://www.partiproductions.com/letterslide_test/index.html

Sure would appreciate some help in getting the width from char1 and assigning it to it's parent sl-wrapper.

Thanks,  Bill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to do with padding - was dynamically being changed had to write script to wait until animation was over and then assign padding which fixed the visual width problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but `.css('width')` returns something like "100px" and `Math.abs("100px")` give `NaN`.

Try with `$('span.char1').width()`.

Also you must remember to add to `width` any `margin` and `padding` values.

Comment: Ok, Just updated demo, it's still pulling 27 - I'm very confused.  When I look at Computed style it's showing 39px, no padding or margin. Note: don't roll over it or it will reset :-)  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: HI GG, Can you help me - I really do need some help - just a newbie and having a hard time understanding why this won't work - thanks,  Bill

Comment: @ GG. Do you know of any other jquery gurus that could help - I would appreciate any assistance in guiding them to my question - thanks, Bill